# Converting date from XMLGregorianCalendar with ZoneId.systemDefault() to timestamp with UTC

Tags: kotlin, serialization, timestamp, utc, objectmapper

I have xml with tag `<Birthday>1994-11-30</Birthday>`
I need convert it to json with `timestamp` date in `utc`. My code:

```kotlin
    fun convertXmlToJson(profile: NotifyGetDocsRqType): JsonNode? {
        return objectMapper.valueToTree(profile.data)
    }
```

`Birthday` field in class `NotifyGetDocsRqType`

```java
@XmlElement(name = "Birthday")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar birthday;
```

As a result I am getting json with Birthday = `786142800000`. By utc this value is `29 November 1994, 21:00:00` (checked here https://www.epochconverter.com)

Configuration for `objectMapper`:

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper() = ObjectMapper()
        .apply {
            disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL)
            enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
            enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
            registerKotlinModule()
            setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
            registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
            registerModule(Jdk8Module())
            setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
        }
```

Why is my code not working? Although I wrote `setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` for `objectMapper`

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be to write a custom `Serializer` for `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

```kotlin
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper() = ObjectMapper()
        .apply {
            disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
            enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_UNKNOWN_ENUM_VALUES_AS_NULL)
            enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT)
            enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)
            registerKotlinModule()
            registerModule(Jdk8Module())
            setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)

            val dateTimeSerializer = XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer(XMLGregorianCalendar::class.java)
            val javaTimeModule = JavaTimeModule()
            javaTimeModule.addSerializer(XMLGregorianCalendar::class.java, dateTimeSerializer)
            registerModule(javaTimeModule)
        }
```

```kotlin
class XMLGregorianCalendarSerializer(clazz: Class<XMLGregorianCalendar>?) : StdSerializer<XMLGregorianCalendar>(clazz) {
    override fun serialize(value: XMLGregorianCalendar?, gen: JsonGenerator?, provider: SerializerProvider?) {
        val utcDateInstant = value?.toLocalDateTime()
            ?.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            ?.toInstant()
        gen?.writeString(utcDateInstant?.toEpochMilli().toString())
    }
}
```

Perhaps there are some more elegant examples of solutions, I will be glad if someone offers them.